What is the correct way in assembly to push a value stored in stack to the stack again?
I am writing a small compiler for my language. Currently the way I am handling variables is by pushing their values to stack and storing their offset. Whenever a variable is needed I push [rsp+offset] and pop it where the value was required. Using NASM for x64 windows, this is the assembly code I Generate for the following code:
num x = 10
exit(x)

extern ExitProcess
section .text
global _start
_start:
        push rbp            ;adding base pointer to stack 
        mov rbp, rsp        ;getting new base pointer
        sub rsp, 32         ;allocating shadow space

        mov rax, 10         ;x = 10, 
        push rax            ;push rax to stack, offset is 0
        push QWORD [rsp+0]  ;push the top of stack pointer to stack because x is needed
        pop rcx             ;top of stack used for exit(x)

        mov ecx, ecx        ;clear top 32bits of rcx
        call ExitProcess    ;exit program

I have tried +8,+4, -8 as offset, I am getting the same error which is -1073741819 which refers to Segment fault or access violation. I also specified default rel for rip-addressing but it still didn't work. What is the correct assembly or what am I doing wrong?
EDIT: I have changed my code to something simpler and am still facing the same issue
code:
default rel
extern ExitProcess
section .text
global _start
_start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    mov rax, 10
    push rax
    mov rcx, rsp
    mov ecx, ecx

    add rsp, 32
    call ExitProcess


This program works on my machine btw, it runs and exits and I get "NatromeTex.exe (process 7916) exited with code 10 (0xa)." if I run it from visual studio

Visual studio uses MASM right? My program needs to use NASM for compatibility reasons, the code doesn't run no matter what offset I try.

I use vsyasm when I want to use NASM-style code in visual studio. Do you know which instruction fails? (you should be able to find out by using a debugger) Could it be call ExitProcess?

It's the push QWORD [rsp+0] the app runs for a long time (5s) and returns -1073741819 as the exit code

That's a very inefficient way to compile vs. emitting mov rcx, [rsp+0].  (Or mov ecx, [rsp+0] in this case to also zero-extend 32 bits.  Or just don't; the calling convention allows high garbage above narrow args, and most math operations (other than right-shift and divide) also give the same result in the low bits you care about.)

Also, Windows x64 requires 16-byte stack alignment before a function call, which you set up with push / sub rsp, 32, but then broke with an odd number of unpopped pushes before a call.  And if you were calling a function which returned, your x would have been part of the shadow space of your callee so it would have been overwritten.  Also, the Windows x64 ABI's stack-unwind metadata needs you to not move RSP mid function, only in the prologue and epilogue.  (But functions with VLAs are still allowed, so maybe that doesn't apply when using RBP as a frame pointer.)

See Shadow space example (including Raymond Chen's comments about unwind metadata for SEH).  And Assembly code, printf and allocating space on the stack for a simple example of doing it wrong, of a function call overwriting the 32 bytes of stack space above its return address.

push qword [rsp+0] is correct NASM syntax for pushing another copy of of the last thing pushed, currently in memory at [rsp].  Should be equivalent to another push rax or a push 10 in your code.  (push qword ptr [rsp] is correct MASM syntax.  In MASM, push qword [rsp] is push [rsp+8] because qword is a constant with value 8, and 8[rsp] is a valid addressing mode.  But you are using NASM which is good; it has far fewer nasty surprises.)

@PeterCordes the idea is that the code generation can push the required value onto the stack and pop it when the code needs it, since the value is pushed and popped before any changes to the stack, the stack will still remain as a list of values of variables and the required value gets sent to the code. Problem is with accessing any variable in rsp. I was wondering as rsp stores the top of the stack it acts like a pointer, so should I "de-reference" it in some way as one would do in C?

Offsets relative to RSP (or RBP if using it as a frame pointer) already give you random access to variables on the stack.  Don't only use it as a stack data-structure, that sucks a lot.  Like if 32-bit x is at [rbp-4], mov ecx, [rbp-4].  Look at how C compilers generate code to access locals, especially in debug mode where they won't keep values in regs across statements, for stuff like int z = x + y;

So the main problem seemed to be that rsp would go out of alignment, the solution was simple enough, add rsp, 8 fixed the code.
fixed assembly:
Basically I had to align the stack pointer after every push before any function call which is call ExitProcess in this case
Fixed assembly v2:
default rel
extern ExitProcess

section .text
global _start
_start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    mov rax, 10
    push rax
    mov rax, 13
    push rax
    push QWORD [rsp+0]
    push QWORD [rsp+8]

    pop rcx
    mov ecx, ecx
    and rsp, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0
    call ExitProcess


Just making sure you know that the add rsp, 8 will effectively undo the push QWORD [rsp+0] discarding the pushed value so what's the point exactly? The pop rcx will get the value from push rax as if the previous two instructions were not there at all. Also you need to allocate 32 bytes of shadow space.

Shadow space is technically necessary since you call ExitProcess. Just because something happens to work does not mean it's correct or that it will always work. Can't tell you why the push [rsp+16] worked (or seemed to work) because you did not show that code.

You also need to declare unwind codes for every time you change rsp

@Jester thank you for showing me that, I realised after I pushed different values onto the stack and popped them.

Why are you reserving shadow shape above the values you're pushing and popping?  Function calls will clobber them.  It doesn't matter for noreturn functions like ExitProcess, but this seems like a pointless example.  Functions you call own the 32 bytes from [rsp+0] to [rsp+31] (before call pushes a return address / after it returns).

typo: shadow space (in my last comment)
